# assign php while array result to a variable number of variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I use this code to echo values from an array generated from a mysql query

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo $row[0]; 
            echo ' ';
            echo $row[1];
            echo "%  ";
            echo "<br>";
    }
```

to produce a result like:

```
CC 77.6% 
CT 21.9% 
TT 0.5%
```

Which is fine.

I would like to have the 3 pairs of values available to use in a bootstrap progress bar div so that I may represent the information in a more visual manner.

How can assign the values from the array into variables?

**EDIT**

Sample result set

```
Array ( 
[0] => AA 
[alleles] => AA 
[1] => 6 
[total] => 6 
[2] => 25.00 
[percentage] => 25.00 ) 

Array ( 
[0] => AG 
[alleles] => AG 
[1] => 11 
[total] => 11 
[2] => 45.83 
[percentage] => 45.83 ) 

Array ( 
[0] => GG 
[alleles] => GG 
[1] => 7 
[total] => 7 
[2] => 29.17 
[percentage] => 29.17 )
```

Comment: is the result of your query a single row ? or you need to aggregate data in any way?

Comment: Array ( [0] => AA [alleles] => AA [1] => 6 [total] => 6 [2] => 25.00 [percentage] => 25.00 ) 
Array ( [0] => AG [alleles] => AG [1] => 11 [total] => 11 [2] => 45.83 [percentage] => 45.83 ) 
Array ( [0] => GG [alleles] => GG [1] => 7 [total] => 7 [2] => 29.17 [percentage] => 29.17 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$values = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   array_push($values, array($row[0], $row[1]))
}
```

Now `$values` is an array of values. For example `$values[0][0]` is equal to "CC", `$values[0][1]` is equal to "77.6" and etc;

Answer (score 0):

In your case, assuming `alleles` is unique, you can buffer your results and create an key-value array:

```
$results = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[ $row['alleles'] ] = array(
        'total' => $row['total'],
        'percentage' => $row['percentage']
    ); }
```

after that, you can access your data in the following way:

`$results['AA']['total']`

and to display all of them:

```
foreach ($results as $k => $data) {
    printf("%s: %s%%<br/>\n", $k, $data['percentage']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use This]
First of all, use two div. first for name of that progress bar. Other one for value.
This is the code dude.. use this..